# How can i change the CURLOPT_URL quickly across multiple pages

Tags: php, url, curl

I am using curl to call up html content from another domain. The url differs slightly on each page using curl but the domain name is the same.

If i want to change just the domain name part of the url in curl, that is being used on 10 pages, how can i achieve this quickly without editing the code on each page?

I have tried using 'include' in the url string but it doesn't work. The 'include' file was just the domain prefix.

Here is my code. The only part that needs changing across all pages is the domain name in the url (mydomain.com) and not the full url extension.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mydomain.com/rssfeeds/htmlarticle.asp");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
print $result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
/* HERE IS YOUR options array where key like RETURN_TRANSFERING 
                                    and value - true */
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
function get($url, $ch){
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  return curl_exec($curl);
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you have a lot of urls, than take a look at this library https://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/ it help you perform multi get requests, so speed will be 2-4 faster than sigle curl request.

**UPDATE2:** Here is another one for multi requests https://github.com/barbushin/multirequest

Comment: -1 it won't work, `$ch` inside the function is not the same `$ch` from outside. Now, of course you can use `global` but it's evil...
If you want to fix your answer - pass `$ch` to the function!

Comment: Think i am a little out of my depth here but thanks for the responses. Is it possible to do something like this so i only have to edit one tpl file. curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "include('includes/url.tpl')rssfeeds/htmlarticle.asp");

Comment: Yes, you can take kirugan's `get()` function and put it in external file and include it in all your files.

Comment: @Kastansa you can read your urls from file, which file() function help and iterate over each url, retrieving it with get($ch, $url);

Comment: Ok great thanks to both of you. Hopefully i will be back in a bit to mark this as solved.